# How to make Teracopy close its window after transferring a file?

Tags: windows, teracopy

For some reason after I transfer a file with TeraCopy it won't automatically close the window when the file was succesfully transferred.

Does anyone know how to change this, since I can't seem to find it in the settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the configuration file of TeraCopy for the NoClose parameter.

The configuration file is located at:

- **XP**: C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\TeraCopy\
- **Vista/Win7**: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\TeraCopy

They explain on [**this page**](http://help.codesector.com/TeraCopyConfiguration):

> NoClose=0
>   0: Close window after successful file transfer.

So I suppose it is not set at 0 for you.

Alternatively, if it is not set by default, you can try clicking the small 'X' at the far right middle of the transfer window, it should highlight.

Comment: You won't believe how long I've been clicking on close... Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Comment by @Joey Connick: I have NoClose=0 in my ini file and it still won't close on completion of the copy. :(

Comment: @IvoFlipse same, seems broken.

Comment: I have NoClose=0 and windows is not closing. :(

Comment: I have the same problem in TeraCopy 3.26. If anybody figures it out, please let me know.